# meteor d3.js communicate event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, meteor, event-handling

I am working with the  meteor-d3-force.js example: Realtime Reactive D3 Force Layout Graph Using Meteor JS.

I have a d3 code in a meteor application. I would like to add an event handler to a d3-defined element, such as:

```
d3.select(#element).on("click",remove()).
```

Then, I would like to achieve something along these lines in meteor

```
// When the element changes, delete
// the element.

Template.chat.events({
'change #element': function () {
Messages.remove(this._id);
}
 });
```

Comment: You probably don't want to call `remove()` but only pass it as an argument, so `.on("click", remove)`.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I found a solution, please see below.

Comment: Would be happy to see some others solutions, still great you figure how to trick it :D

Answer (score 0):

My solution: with event.target.id I can access the baseVal of the svg element and use it to update the database:

```
 Template.body.events({

    "click .circle-type1": function (event) {
     // removes Node also from mongod by _id
     Nodes.remove(event.target.id);
   }
  });
```

Do the inspection with console.log(events);

The circle is created in typical manner in d3.js and has an

.on("click",remove())

handler attached. Overall I am getting the functionality: that I can add or remove elements form the meteor template.events, but also remove on click of the d3.js element while updating the collection with the event function as shown.